# JQuery filtering (finding a val and using the associated text)

Tags: jquery

I have a problem filtering through a options list to find items.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nel_mo/q819L9jp/)

I want to filter through the options finding a value of '501' for example and grabbing the Text value from that to use somewhere else.

```
<select id="media_keywords" class="chosen-select" multiple="" style="width: 350px;">
    <option value="504">Alpha</option>
    <option class="optionFound" value="502">Bravo</option>
    <option value="501">Foxtrot</option>
    <option value="503">Zulu</option>
</select>
```

here is the Jquery i tried

```
$( "select" )
    .css( "background", "#b4b0da" )
    .filter(function( index ) {
        $( this ).attr( "value" ) === "501";
    })
    .addClass("optionFound");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .find() to search for options and return to get the element

```
$( "select" )
  .css( "background", "#b4b0da" )
  .find('option')
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return this.value== "501";
  }).addClass('optionFound');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q819L9jp/1/)

Or without filter like this using attribute selector

```
$( "select" )
  .css( "background", "#b4b0da" )
  .find('option[value="501"]')
  .addClass('optionFound');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q819L9jp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var val = $('select')
    .css('background', '#b4b0da')
    .find('option[value="501"]')
    .text();
```